# Simple but broken ternary conditional expression in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, promise, ternary-operator

TypeScript 2.7 lets me do this:

```
const promise = Promise.resolve();
promise.then(() => {});
```

And it lets me do this:

```
const promise = new Promise(() => {});
promise.then(() => {});
```

So why can't I do this?

```
const promise = true
  ? Promise.resolve()
  : new Promise(() => {});

promise.then(() => {});
```

This example breaks on the official TypeScript PlayGround, too:

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20promise%20%3D%20true%0D%0A%20%20%3F%20Promise.resolve()%0D%0A%20%20%3A%20new%20Promise(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Apromise.then(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%7D)%3B

Here's the compilation error:

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '(<TResult1 = void, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: void) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResul...' has no compatible call signatures.

I can "fix" the error by specifying the type of `promise` from `Promise<void> | Promise<{}>` to `Promise<void | {}>`:

```
const promise: Promise<void | {}> = true
  ? Promise.resolve()
  : new Promise(() => {});

promise.then(() => {});
```

Why?

Comment: You may be interested in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the type of your promise is:

```
const promise: Promise<void> | Promise<{}>
```

Change it to this for example:

```
const promise = true
  ? Promise.resolve()
  : new Promise<void>(() => {}); // Note the explicit generic type parameter.

promise.then(() => {});
```

---

This might be due an assignability issue, e.g.:

```
let x: (a: void) => void = () => { };
let y: (a: {}) => void = () => { };

y = x; // Type '(a: void) => void' is not assignable to type '(a: {}) => void'.
x = y; // Type '(a: {}) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer! Why am I unable to call `then` on `Promise<void> | Promise<{}>` despite being able to on both types individually?

Comment: I think that's it! Each type's `then` method _technically_ has a different signature, which is why `then` cannot be invoked on a union of those types. It doesn't matter that both `then` methods are able to accept the same parameters.

Comment: @FeelingHurt: Types are weird sometimes :)